# How to get a smooth ROC curve from CNN with keras functional API?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, probability, roc, functional-api

I use the following code:

```
fpr, tpr, t = roc_curve(true_categories, predicted_categories)
```

I know the **predicted_categories** should be probability or confidence.

But as predict_proba() seems not working for keras Functional API, how should I get the predicted_categories right?

I tried

```
predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

and the ROC looks like this:

[ROC with a sharp angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntIE1.png)

and this

```
predicted_categories =  = tf.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

the ROC looks like this:

[an ROC with AUC ~50%, which should be 85%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkjDS.png)

Both of them are not what I expected...

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try just providing the model output as scores, without any processing, because predict_proba is not necessary here, your model likely outputs probabilities already.

Comment: I did think of this method. However, the original output "y_pred" has a shape of (114, 2), which does not fit the roc_curve() function. It return error: "multilabel-indicator format is not supported"...